# Changing my shared hosting nameservers to cloudflare nameservers

Tags: dns, cloudflare, nameservers

I have signed up with cloudflare and i am running a website on shared hosting. I changed the nameservers of my domain on the shared hosting. I was expecting the website to not be available since i changed the nameservers but that has not happened yet.

I plan on confirming my domain on mailgun and having business email with google g-suite which both require i update srv settings in my domain.

My question is, why is my website still not offline and will the g-suite and mailgun changes be now done on the domain control panel or from cloudflare?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you changed the records at your registrar to connect to cloudflare, and then provide the appropriate A (or combination of A and CNAME) records in cloudflare you will be able to connect properly to your shared hosting and manage DNS records like SRV directly at cloudflare.